# Let $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\in G$. Prove $a_1\circ\dots\circ a_n$ is unique, regardless of the order $n$ in which operations are carried out.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with binary operation $\circ$. Let $a_1,a_2,....,a_n\in G$. Prove that $a_1\circ a_2\circ...\circ a_n$ is unique, regardless of the order $n$ in which operations are carried out.

I thought associativity might be helpful.
By associativity, $a_1\circ a_2\circ a_3=(a_1\circ a_2)\circ a_3=a_1\circ( a_2\circ a_3).$

I couldn't conclude something helpful.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use induction on $n$.

Comment: Do the list of elements $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ exhaust $G$, i.e. are they all the elements of $G$?

Comment: @Jeffrey Wang: Could you show me some steps I am feeling hard to do?

Comment: What does it mean for some element to be "unique"? Do you mean $a_1\circ a_2\circ\cdots\circ a_n$?

Comment: @JeffreyWang, I agree with the OP that more of a hint would be helpful. This looks like it calls for a surprisingly subtle induction argument. The number of ways to parenthesize a product grows like a Catalan number, and you have to account for all of them when you induct.

Comment: @5xum, I'm sure that's what the OP meant. (Good catch. I didn't even notice there were missing ellipses.)

Comment: @5xum: I have edited. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250060.